# Deadlock between two select

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, sql-server-2016

I am having a typical situation of a deadlock between two select statements.
I have a JMS listener running, handling two jms message at the same time.

They both run a select query and i end up with a key lock on the same table all the time. This is the details of the deadlock.

```
<deadlock-list>
 <deadlock victim="process276e56fcca8">
  <process-list>
   <process id="process276e56fcca8" taskpriority="0" logused="764" waitresource="KEY: 7:72057594422558720 (8e392f9a7525)" waittime="4129" ownerId="24935297" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2017-09-02T10:01:18.853" XDES="0x276dd31f7b8" lockMode="S" schedulerid="5" kpid="25308" status="suspended" spid="65" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2017-09-02T10:01:18.963" lastbatchcompleted="2017-09-02T10:01:18.963" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.963" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="GAETAN-PC" hostpid="0" loginname="fundhive" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="24935297" currentdb="7" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtend="274" sqlhandle="0x02000000ad097723a3df0ffd0ae8c2aae2d6e9938b5224fa0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
select * ,61 as userId  from getDocumentWorkflowMessages(20285)  where 1=1 and vehicleGroupId = &apos;10372&apos; and investorLevelGroupId = &apos;13933&apos;     </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process276f302fc28" taskpriority="0" logused="764" waitresource="KEY: 7:72057594422558720 (7d9127e683cc)" waittime="4188" ownerId="24935134" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2017-09-02T10:01:18.690" XDES="0x27671594728" lockMode="S" schedulerid="3" kpid="13788" status="suspended" spid="73" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2017-09-02T10:01:18.783" lastbatchcompleted="2017-09-02T10:01:18.783" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.783" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="GAETAN-PC" hostpid="0" loginname="fundhive" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="24935134" currentdb="7" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtend="274" sqlhandle="0x0200000046471c35dd8038f6b5d5a8a05c3680d8fe3b66dc0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
select * ,61 as userId  from getDocumentWorkflowMessages(20285)  where 1=1 and vehicleGroupId = &apos;10385&apos; and investorLevelGroupId = &apos;14481&apos;     </inputbuf>
   </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594422558720" dbid="7" objectname=" DocumentWorkflowStatuses" indexname="idx_DocumentWorkflowStatuses_isArchived" id="lock276c4fac900" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594422558720">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process276f302fc28" mode="X"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process276e56fcca8" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594422558720" dbid="7" objectname=" DocumentWorkflowStatuses" indexname="idx_DocumentWorkflowStatuses_isArchived" id="lock276e1728600" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594422558720">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process276e56fcca8" mode="X"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process276f302fc28" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
  </resource-list>
 </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

I read lots of post but i am not sure how to approach the problem. I tried with and without an index on the table DocumentWorkflowStatus but it's the same things.

This is the getDocumentWorkflowMessages query :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getDocumentWorkflowMessages]
    (
        @projectId bigint 
    )
RETURNS TABLE
RETURN 
    SELECT t.*
        ,dbo.WorkflowStatuses.id AS workflowStatusId
        ,(
            CASE
                WHEN isnull(t.workflowScheme_fk, - 1) = - 1 -- IS NULL
                    THEN ''
                ELSE dbo.WorkflowStatuses.NAME
                END
            ) AS workflowStateName
        ,dbo.WorkflowStatuses.id AS workflowStateId
        ,CASE
            WHEN isnull(t.workflowScheme_fk, '') = ''
                THEN - 1
            WHEN WorkflowStatusCategories.id IS NOT NULL
                THEN WorkflowStatusCategories.id
            ELSE isnull((
                        SELECT TOP 1 id
                        FROM dbo.getWorstWorkflowIdForStructure(t.projectLanguageId, t.vehicleGroupId, t.investorLevelGroupId, t.structureId)
                        ), - 1)
            END AS worstWorkflowCategoryId
    from
        dbo.getProjectDetailView(@projectId,1) t
            LEFT JOIN  
            dbo.DocumentWorkflowStatuses docs ON docs.structure_fk = t.structureId
                                            AND  isnull(docs.versionLanguage_fk, - 1) = isnull(t.projectLanguageId, - 1)
                                            AND  isnull(docs.vehicleGroup_fk, 0) = isnull(t.vehicleGroupId, 0)
                                            AND  isnull(docs.vehicleInvestorGroup_fk, 0) = isnull(t.investorLevelGroupId, 0)
                                            AND  isnull(docs.country_fk, 0) = isnull(t.countryId,0)

                LEFT JOIN  
            dbo.WorkflowStatuses 
                                ON WorkflowStatuses.id = docs.workflowStatus_fk
                LEFT JOIN
            dbo.WorkflowStatusCategories  
                                        ON WorkflowStatusCategories.id = WorkflowStatuses.workflowStatusCategory_fk

        GO
```

This is my index :

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_DocumentWorkflowStatuses_isArchived
ON [dbo].[DocumentWorkflowStatuses] ([structure_fk],[versionLanguage_fk],[vehicleGroup_fk],[vehicleInvestorGroup_fk],[country_fk])
INCLUDE ( [workflowStatus_fk])
GO
```

Comment: select will never take an x lock on table and also you are missing some  info  ..`getDocumentWorkflowMessages` takes one parameter in deadlock,but your query doesnt resemble this

Comment: i have update the query getDocumentWorkflowMessages to reflect what is really is

Comment: Is there something down in those TVF that use this index?

Comment: Both of them have used transaction log so must be in the same transaction as a data modification statement happening prior to the select.

Comment: @MartinSmith you are right, there is an update statement prior the select statement, both running in the same transaction. Should i have two separate transaction ?

Comment: @JM_ there is yes but not related to the Table DocumentWorkflowStatuses